# What database engine should I go for this particular scenario?

Tags: php, mongodb, amazon-ec2, couchdb, amazon-simpledb

I'm currently using Amazon SimpleDB. But it seems, by the cost, that it will be too expensive as to what I can afford.

I've one m1.small Amazon EC2 instance which runs the front-end web server very well. In my single SDB domain, I've four attributes (two of which I can delete since they have data I rarely need now) and the item name. I perform only getAttribute queries (no selects). Bascially, the item name is what I use to find data.

Around 20 reads and 8 writes per second occur on it. The box usage is terribly high which pushes my costs up.

Which would be the best database choice, hosted on a t1.micro instance (since it's the only cheap and low-level 64-bit instance and other 64-bit instances are far too expensive)?

Redis/MongoDB/CouchDB or what? Would it be even possible to host a database server that can sustain the load I mentioned above on so small an instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have migrated some of my databases from **SimpleDB** to **MongoDB**  for other reasons.

However, I wanted to continue with the hosted model for the database. So instead of using Amazon SimpleDB I am now using a combination of MongoHQ (mongohq.com) and MongoLab (mongolab.com).

They also have a free tier, not based on traffic but on the size of your database.  You will need to analyze the costs based on the amount of data you will be dealing with.
It seems to me that if you are only using 2 attributes you should be fine with the free tier for a while  (*MongoLab.com has a 250Mb limit for the free tier*)

Since both of those hosted service can be hosted in Amazon EC2, they are close to your front end, you will not incur in bandwidth costs because they are all inside AWS, and will help with performance since you will be using the high-speed internal AWS network.

In terms of performance I think 20 reads and 8 writes per second is not a big deal and the server will take care of all the cycles needed to support your app.

You can batch all your writes and use the default that provides no response to make the writes much faster.

For your reads, make sure you index your collection correctly and it should run fine.